# Lighttpd reverse proxy to another server faild

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, lighttpd

I am trying lighttpd as a reverse proxy
(v1.4.53)

```
lighttpd.conf:
$HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/example/)" {
    proxy.header = ("map-urlpath" => ( "/example/" => "/" ))
    proxy.server = ("" => (( "host" => "redmine.lighttpd.net" )))
}
```

However, this request returns response code **404**.

```
http://localhost/example/ --> http://www.exapmle.com/   ...404
http://localhost/example/pro/lighttpd/ --> http://www.exapmle.com/pro/lighttpd/  ...404
http://localhost/example/pro/lighttpd/wiki --> http://www.exapmle.com/pro/lighttpd/wiki  ...404
```

Is there a mistake in this mod_proxy setting.
Also, how do I output mod_proxy debug log details.

Comment: There was a mistake in the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake in the explanation.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/example/)" {
    proxy.header = ("map-urlpath" => ( "/example/" => "/" ))
    proxy.server = ("" => (( "host" => "www.exapmle.com" )))
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a mistake in this mod_proxy setting. Also, how do I output mod_proxy debug log details.
> `"host" => "www.exapmle.com"`

You need to go to your server at [www.exapmle.com](http://www.exapmle.com) (sic) and see if it is receiving requests and what it is receiving.

In your lighttpd.conf make sure that you are loading `"mod_proxy"` in `server.modules`.

Test your lighttpd config on the command line: `lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`
and review any warnings or errors.